# Calculate and Reduce Bandwidth of my Android application

Tags: android, bandwidth

My application connects to server and fetches information, Hence i want to calculate the bandwidth utilized by my application and reduce it as far as possible for faster performance.

How do I do this ?

Comment: what do you mean by bandwidth?

Comment: How do you "fetch information"?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest (R17) tools and an Android 4.0.3+ device, [you can measure bandwidth via DDMS](http://tools.android.com/recent/detailednetworkusageinddms).

Otherwise, you will need to use a utility that works off of `TrafficStats`, or integrate `TrafficStats` data collection in your own code.

Comment: can you please let me know a bit more about this `TrafficStats` ?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html